# Pika adapters cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5672

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to fix [unfinished module](https://github.com/GTB3NW/SteamTradingServices/blob/master/Exchange/exchange.py) for use in project, unfortunately, while trying to launching entry function of module ( `main()` ), i got an error.

At first, i got multiple errors, because if you look at original version of module, it's like this:

```
@click.option("--rmqhost", default="localhost", help="Rabbitmq host details")
@click.option("--redishost", default="localhost", help="Redis host details")
```

which uses IPv6 but my system is using IPv4.

---

But after i solved the first problem, now i got another one with IPv4:

Full log:

> ```
> >>> from Exchange.exchange import main
> >>> main()
> INFO:Exchange.exchange:Exchange Service is starting
> INFO:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5672
> WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: [Errno 61] Connection refused
> WARNING:pika.connection:Could not connect, 0 attempts left
> ERROR:Exchange.exchange:Couldn't connect to rabbitmq, exiting!
> ```

What may the problem be? Is port **5672** occupied? Because when i tried `lsof l :5672` in bash, it returned 0 (nothing). If not, then whats the problem and how could i fix it?

Comment: Run `netstat -tulpn | grep :5672` and view what process is using such port.

Comment: @vishes_shell It gave me this error: `netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`, but i tried `lsof -i :5672` and it returned.

Comment: And the result if RabbitMQ?

Comment: @vishes_shell I didn't understand question sorry, `rmqhost` didn't gave me any errors as seen in log.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being completely clear, with first command i just wanted you to see if your 5672 port is used by rabbitmq or not.

Comment: @vishes_shell I think nothing uses 5672 at the time because it returns 0, so there is another problem?

Comment: Have you started `rabbitmq-server`?

Comment: @vishes_shell Oh, i didn't, i actually have little experience rabbitmq and redis, i'm gonna try creating it now.

Comment: @vishes_shell Thanks, it worked, got another error, but i think i'm going to be able to fix it.